CAS cas-overlay-template stuck at 94%
I'm following this tutorial:
https://fawnoos.com/2022/03/04/cas65-gettingstarted-overlay/
So I entered the following commands:
curl -k https://getcas.apereo.org/starter.tgz  -d type=cas-overlay -d baseDir=overlay | tar -xzvf -
./gradlew clean
./gradlew clean copyCasConfiguration build
./gradlew build jibDockerBuild

But on the last command the code is stuck in a loop on 94%. The output is gibberish. Anyone know what to do?
The output:
←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 29s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0
;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 30s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 31s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43
m 32s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 33s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 34s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m
<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 35s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 36s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;
39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 37s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 38s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m
 39s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 40s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 41s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [43m 42s]←[m←[39D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m============←[0;39;1m-> 94% EXECUTING [4

